# has_one association without foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have such models `Supplier` and `Role`.
Supplier should have one role, one role might belongs to multiple suppliers,
so I don't want to add foreign key to the Role model
I wan't to create all roles at the beginning and then add role to a supplier whenever I want
 Is there a way to do that??

Comment: RE your title: associations without foreign keys are impossible. One model or the other needs to have a foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign key in this case needs to go in `Supplier`. You can't put it in `Role`, if a `Role` can belong to many suppliers.

That makes this a `belongs_to` relationship by Rails convention, not a `has_one`.

Your `Supplier` needs a column called `role_id` and an association `belongs_to :role`. Your `Role` can then have a `has_many :suppliers`, if you want to be able to find all suppliers who use a given role.